# install apache2 not Thread-Safe on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04

I MUST develop application with **PHP 5.5.9** version of PHP. For that I download source et compiling those manually. My version of **PHP is not thread-safe** (I don't find the Thread-safe version).

I would like to use **Apache2** web server in my **Ubuntu 14.04** version of OS System.

I try 2 kind of installation :

- `apt-get -y install apache2-mpm-worker`
- `apt-get -y install apache2-mpm-prefork`

But when I try to restart apache I have this error message (for 2 kind of intallation!) : "`Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe`"

I don't understand because on the web all say that worker is not thread safe.
I would like to use **Apache2 (with apxs2) not Thread-safe for PHP** not thread-safe. But all installation tell me that Apache2 is Thread-safe.

Can you help me to have this technical structure web :
PHP 5.5.9 (not thread-safe) + Apache2 (not thread-safe) with apxs2 (for compiling PHP with source)

I don't find any : "`LoadModule xxxxxxxxx modules/xxxxxxxx.so`" in my apache2.conf

Comment: have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/a/705305/615196

Comment: Why aren't you using Apache's FastCGI capabilities and `PHP-FPM`? You're on Linux, you aren't using thread safe version of PHP, you have access to `epoll` - where's the problem and why would you load PHP as Apache module instead of proxy to fastcgi endpoint? Funny part is that using Apache as FastCGI proxy will 100% yield better performance and so much less hassle.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why you compile it from sources? php 5.5.9 is available as a deb package out of the box on ubuntu 14.04: `lsb_release -d; apt-cache show php5 | grep Version
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Version: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.20`

Comment: when I try to apt-gt install php5 on ubuntu 14.04 I have the 5.5.38 of PHP. I don't know how install exactly php 5.5.9 on ubuntu 14.04. apt-get install php can't select exact version.

Comment: I launched this add-apt-repository command before install php5 'main', 'universe', 'restricted' and 'multiverse'. But I re again install php5 packahe on ubuntu 14.04 and I have php5.5.9 installed. @Alex Blex : Can you reply with complete response and I valid this ? Thank a lot

Comment: @darkomen, Good to know it helped, but it by no means answers the question.